# docker-compose use pipe in command

Tags: pipe, docker-compose

I am having trouble running the following in docker-compose (1.7 build 0d7bf73
, compose file format version 1) which works fine from command line (docker 1.10.3):

```
docker run --rm --entrypoint="/bin/bash" node:4 -c "node gridd.js -t | ./node_modules/bunyan/bin/bunyan"
```

My docker compose:

```
grid:
  image: node:4-slim
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  command: -c "node gridd.js -t | ./node_modules/bunyan/bin/bunyan"
```

Using this docker-compose file results in

```
marcel@client ~/grid $ docker-compose -f ../docker-compose-test.yml -p test up
Removing test_grid_1
Recreating 4e0104efc149_4e0104efc149_4e0104efc149_test_grid_1

ERROR: for grid  Container command not found or does not exist.
Attaching to
```

I also tried using the exec method, docker-compose command as list with the same results

Answer (score 3):

In 2021, with `docker-compose` v2.0.0-beta.6:

Behaviour of the `command` field is surprising, if `|` or `&&` are involved.

**Expected**

I can freely use piping and `&&` in the commands; they would be poured to `bash -c`.

I think this is the Docker normal; there behaviour of `command` field is different between providing it as a string vs. as an array.

**Actual**

The command seems simply to get cut at `|` or `&&`, and the tail ignored!!!

What's bad is that there's no error about this. Also, did not find any documentation telling how exactly the `command` contents are used (in Docker, there is such documentation).

---

Experimentation (below) shows that if I start the command with `bash -c` explicitly, I can use `|` and `&&` in the commands.

Note: Behaviour is the same with syntax version 3.9 (latest).

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  abc:
    image: debian:latest
    #command: 'echo a | grep -v a'   # a (wrong)
    #command: 'echo a | grep x'      # a (wrong)
    #
    #command: bash -c 'echo a | grep -v a'   # (empty) 
    #command: bash -c 'echo a | grep a'   # a 
    command: bash -c 'echo a && false'   # (exits with code 1)
```

To test:

- paste the above to `docker-compose.yml`
- `docker compose up`

> Note: With slightly longer commands, one ends up doing quote escape trickery if the full command is also quoted. Thus, I left  `bash -c` without quotes.

Comment: oh no... how can i do like printf 'y' | ping

Comment: @ji-ruh You just use the `sh -c` (or `bash -c`) in front, and it will be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this must be a bug in docker-compose. As soon as I move the docker-compose.yml file to the current directory and don't specify it with -f flag, everything works :)